# Multiple specifications for same function in Erlang header file

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to specify a function in a header file.
Like so:

```
-spec update(pid(), tuple(tuple(), integer(), atom()), tuple(atom(), atom())) -> tuple(tuple(), integer(), atom()).
```

Now I want to add some extra specification for this function because it has multiple different parameters.

```
update(_Pid, {Specs, infinity, _State}, {Step}) ->
  timer:sleep(10000),
  {{Specs, infinity}, {Step}};
update(_Pid, {Specs, infinity, _State}, {ExtraInfo, Step}) ->
  timer:sleep(10000),
  {{Specs, infinity}, {ExtraInfo, Step}};
update(_Pid, {Specs, N, _State}, _Info) when N < 2 ->
  {Specs, N, stop};
update(_Pid, {Specs, N, _State}, {notTaken, Step}) ->
  {Specs, N, Step};
update(_Pid, {Specs, N, _State}, {taken, Step}) ->
  {Specs, N - 1, Step}.
```

So I want to add these extra specifications, for the different parameters in this function, in my header file. I don't know how to do this, could someone help me with this?

I tried to do this but it gives me compilation errors:

```
-spec update(pid(), tuple(tuple(), integer(), atom()), tuple(atom(), atom())) -> tuple(tuple(), integer(), atom()).
-spec update(pid(), tuple(tuple(), atom(), atom()), tuple(integer(), atom())) -> tuple(tuple(), atom(), atom()).
-spec update(pid(), tuple(tuple(), atom(), atom()), tuple(atom())) -> tuple(tuple(), atom(), atom()).
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html). I had to use the semi-colon `;`. I changed this:

```
-spec update(pid(), tuple(tuple(), integer(), atom()), tuple(atom(), atom())) -> tuple(tuple(), integer(), atom()).
-spec update(pid(), tuple(tuple(), atom(), atom()), tuple(integer(), atom())) -> tuple(tuple(), atom(), atom()).
-spec update(pid(), tuple(tuple(), atom(), atom()), tuple(atom())) -> tuple(tuple(), atom(), atom()).
```

into this:

```
-spec update(pid(), tuple(tuple(), integer(), atom()), tuple(atom(), atom())) -> tuple(tuple(), integer(), atom());
            (pid(), tuple(tuple(), atom(), atom()), tuple(integer(), atom())) -> tuple(tuple(), atom(), atom());
            (pid(), tuple(tuple(), atom(), atom()), tuple(atom())) -> tuple(tuple(), atom(), atom()).
```

Comment: That is correct. Can I ask why you want to put it in a header file, though?

Comment: For making my code robust and it has functionality that can be duplicated.

Comment: Have you considered using the -callback mechanism with behaviours? They let you put the type specification on the behaviour definition rather than repeating it in many places.

Comment: I've searched it but I don't think it is necessary for my case (for now anyway). But thanks for the advice